# How to restart Nginx on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, nginx, mac

I just installed Nginx on Mac OS X (thanks http://www.kevinworthington.com/nginx-mac-os-snow-leopard-2-minutes/), but **how do I restart Nginx on Mac OS X?**

Thanks!

Comment: If you just want to restart because of an updated config then just do `sudo nginx -s reload`.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

```
sudo nginx -s stop && sudo nginx
```

Comment: Quick question what does the `&&` means? I guess it's something different then using `;`?

Comment: @hobbes3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152659/bash-sh-difference-between-and

Comment: this answer is not working for brew installed nginx

Comment: It seems to work for my brew installed nginx in 2019.

Comment: It doesn't work for my brew installed nginx.

Answer (score 56):

For a one-liner, you could just do:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

The `-s` options stands for signal, and is the option you'll use to send `stop`, `quit`, `reopen` and `reload` signals to nginx.

For more info on the options, just do `nginx -h` for a list of all of them and their functions.

Cheers!

Comment: This did not work for me so I had to actually do `sudo nginx` to get it to start. I think it had something to do with nginx already being stopped in my case.

Comment: Could you do `sudo nginx -s reload || sudo nginx` instead?

Answer (score 30):

for brew installation: `sudo brew services restart nginx`

Comment: This command dosn't work for me at all. I install nginx via brew...

Comment: @kris_IV what is the output?

Comment: after start:  `brew services restart nginx` i get response:
`Stopping `nginx`... (might take a while)`
`==> Successfully stopped `nginx` (label: homebrew.mxcl.nginx)`
`==> Successfully started `nginx` (label: homebrew.mxcl.nginx)`

Comment: @kris_IV and why do you think this command not working then? everything is fine according to your output

Comment: I know that the output is OK, but new config doesn't work at all, but when I use `sudo nginx -s stop && sudo nginx` instead everything is OK and new config work.

Comment: It's the right command to start via services, but sudo is not needed. Nginx can be started also by calling the executable `nginx`

Comment: It looked good on `brew services restart nginx`

Comment: This wasted me hours. It looks like it worked, but it's better to just use nginx correctly rather than doing so through brew.

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo pkill nginx   
sudo nginx
```

If the `pkill` can't be found, then install it using `brew install proctools` first.

Comment: The above answers are much cleaner than this and enable nginx to stop gracefully.

Comment: This came in handy when nginx started misbehaving and I couldn't kill it with `sudo nginx -s quit` or `sudo -s reload`

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using **brew**:

To see all services:

```
brew services list
```

Start nginx service:

```
brew services start nginx
```

Stop nginx Service:

```
brew services stop nginx
```

Answer (score 1):

sudo nginx -s quit && sudo nginx

Checkout [nginx guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html)

Comment: This does the job, but are you sure a proper shell script does not exist? This method is very raw.

Comment: At least, this is the official documentation. For sure, I will follow the hereby solution also. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using MAMP and Nginx? Then you have an installed script:

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/restartNginx.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another note, if you want to start nginx with launchctl, when your Mac boots up, you can do as follows:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/opt/nginx/*.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
```

In short, you need to put your `plist` file in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, not in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` like the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) instructions. Finally, use the `-w` option with `launchctl`. For further information, follow [this](https://derickbailey.com/2014/12/27/how-to-start-nginx-on-port-80-at-mac-osx-boot-up-log-in/) guide.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed nginx with brew and you started it as a service `brew services start nginx` then you can issue: `brew services restart nginx`